# Easiest way to eliminate NULLs in SELECT DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that is fairly similar the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (a char(1), b char(1))

INSERT INTO #test(a,b) VALUES 
('A',NULL),
('A','B'),
('B',NULL),
('B',NULL)

SELECT DISTINCT a,b FROM #test

DROP TABLE #test
```

The result is, unsurprisingly,

```
a   b
-------
A   NULL
A   B
B   NULL
```

The output I would like to see in actuality is:

```
a   b
-------
A   B
B   NULL
```

That is, if a column has a value in some records but not in others, I want to throw out the row with NULL for that column.  However, if a column has a NULL value for all records, I want to preserve that NULL.

What's the simplest/most elegant way to do this in a single query?

I have a feeling that this would be simple if I weren't exhausted on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: Can a value of column `a` have more than one non-null value in `b`? If that is the case, are you expecting to get both values?

Comment: Sorry, I just got back to this today. For all records in the group, each column is either: 100% populated with a single value, 100% NULL, or partially populated with a single value and partially NULL.

For example: (1, 2, NULL),(1, 2, NULL),(1, NULL, NULL) should reduce to (1, 2, NULL).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct * from test
where b is not null or a in (
  select a from test
  group by a
  having max(b) is null)
```

You can get the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96155/1).

Note if you can only have one non-null value in `b`, this can be simplified to:

```
select a, max(b) from test
group by a
```

Comment: The second does what I need in this case.  Each column is entirely NULL, entirely populated with a single value, or partially populated with a single value and partially NULL. MAX() solves the problem elegantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
create table test(
x char(1),
y char(1)
);

insert into test(x,y) values
('a',null),
('a','b'),
('b', null),
('b', null)
```

Query:

```
with has_all_y_null as
(
    select x
    from test
    group by x
    having sum(case when y is null then 1 end) = count(x)
)
select distinct x,y from test
where 

    (
        -- if a column has a value in some records but not in others,
        x not in (select x from has_all_y_null) 

        -- I want to throw out the row with NULL
        and y is not null 
    )
    or 
    -- However, if a column has a NULL value for all records, 
    -- I want to preserve that NULL
    (x in (select x from has_all_y_null))

order by x,y
```

Output:

```
 X    Y
 A    B
 B    NULL
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/259d6/16

**EDIT**

Seeing [Mosty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10254603/11432), I simplified my code:

```
with has_all_y_null as
(
    select x
    from test
    group by x

    -- having sum(case when y is null then 1 end) = count(x) 
    -- should have thought of this instead of the code above. Mosty's logic is good:
    having max(y) is null
)
select distinct x,y from test
where 
    y is not null
    or 
    (x in (select x from has_all_y_null))
order by x,y
```

I just prefer CTE approach, it has a more self-documenting logic :-)

You can also put documentation on non-CTE approach, if you are conscious of doing so:

```
select distinct * from test
where b is not null or a in 
  ( -- has all b null
  select a from test
  group by a
  having max(b) is null)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #test
    )
    SELECT a,b
    FROM CTE        
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 9999 ELSE b END ;
```

Comment: Could you please add a short description on how your solution works?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just put here a mix of two answers that solved my issue, because my View was more complex

```
    --IdCompe int,
    --Nome varchar(30),
    --IdVanBanco int,
    --IdVan int
    --FlagAtivo bit,
    --FlagPrincipal bit

    select IdCompe
           , Nome
           , max(IdVanBanco)
           , max(IdVan)
           , CAST(MAX(CAST(FlagAtivo as INT)) AS BIT) FlagAtivo
           , CAST(MAX(CAST(FlagPrincipal as INT)) AS BIT) FlagPrincipal
    from VwVanBanco
           where IdVan = {IdVan} or IdVan is null
           group by IdCompe, Nome order by IdCompe asc
```

Thanks to [mosty mostacho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268273/mosty-mostacho) and
          [kenwarner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55948/kenwarner)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.a, t.b
FROM   #test t
WHERE  b IS NOT NULL
OR     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #test u WHERE t.a = u.a AND u.b IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY t.a, t.b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really weird requirement. I wonder how you need it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM   test t
WHERE  NOT ( b IS  NULL
          AND EXISTS 
              ( SELECT * 
                FROM test ta 
                WHERE ta.a = t.a 
                  AND ta.b IS NOT NULL
               ) 
             )
  AND  NOT ( a IS  NULL
          AND EXISTS 
              ( SELECT * 
                FROM test tb 
                WHERE tb.b = t.b 
                  AND tb.a IS NOT NULL
               ) 
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't particularly like this solution, but it seems the most appropriate to me.  Note that your description of what you want sounds exactly like what you get with a LEFT JOIN, so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.a, b.b
FROM #test a
    LEFT JOIN #test b ON a.a = b.a
        AND b.b IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a,b FROM #test t where b is not null
union
SELECT a,b FROM #test t where b is null
and not exists(select 1 from #test where a=t.a and b is not null)
```

Result:

```
a    b
---- ----
A    B
B    NULL
```