# How to use GROUP BY syntax in this multi-JOIN statement with a CASE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT s.s_id, s.t_id, c.c_id, c.desc, sm.user_id
FROM s s
INNER JOIN c c
ON s.c_id=c.c_id
INNER JOIN sm sm
ON s.t_id = sm.t_id
WHERE s.c_id=8;
```

Which returns the following result set

```
s.s_id  s.t_id  c.c_id  c.desc     sm.user_id
3       123     8       something  2
3       123     8       something  2
3       123     8       something  1
4       456     8       something  2
4       456     8       something  2
```

I would like to

1. create an additional column in the result set that indicates whether
   a user owns the product
   (This involves using the `CASE` syntax)
2. and to only display those
       unique `s.s_id` (this involves using `GROUP BY s.s_id`)

For example if `s.c_id=8` and `sm.user_id=1` the result set would be

```
s.s_id  s.t_id  c.c_id  c.desc      sm.user_id does_user_own_product
3       123     8       something   1          yes
4       456     8       something   2          no
```

When `s.s_id=3`, the value of `does_user_own_product` is `yes` since there's at least one `sm.user_id=1 WHERE s.s_id=3`.
When `s.s_id=4`, the value of `does_user_own_product` is `no` since there's no  `sm.user_id=1 WHERE s.s_id=4`.

For example if `s.c_id=8` and `sm.user_id=2` the result set would be

```
s.s_id  s.t_id  c.c_id  c.desc      sm.user_id does_user_own_product
3       123     8       something   1          yes
4       456     8       something   2          yes
```

When `s.s_id=3`, the value of `does_user_own_product` is `yes` since there's at least one `sm.user_id=2 WHERE s.s_id=3`.
When `s.s_id=4`, the value of `does_user_own_product` is `yes` since there's at least one  `sm.user_id=2 WHERE s.s_id=4`.

What would be the appropriate query to achieve the above two subsets given I provide a value of `s.c_id` and `sm.user_id`

**EDIT**
I realize there's some confusion about what it means for a users to own a product.

If a user's id can be found in sm.user_id then a user owns that s.s_id

So for example, in the original result set

```
s.s_id  s.t_id  c.c_id  c.desc     sm.user_id
3       123     8       something  2
3       123     8       something  2
3       123     8       something  1
4       456     8       something  2
4       456     8       something  2
```

Users 1 and 2 own s.s_id 3 and only user 2 owns s.s_id 4

Comment: it's not clear. which column is the product?

Comment: if the value for at least one `sm.user_id` record matches the specified value for `sm.user_id` for each `s.s_id` then that user 'owns' the product.  Does that make sense, It's a little confusing

Comment: Just edited my original post to clarify what it means to 'own' a product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT s.s_id, s.t_id, c.c_id, c.desc, sm.user_id,
  MAX(sm.user_id = @userid) AS does_user_own_product
FROM s s
INNER JOIN c c
ON s.c_id=c.c_id
INNER JOIN sm sm
ON s.t_id = sm.t_id
WHERE s.c_id=8
GROUP BY s.s_id;
```

Although, to be honest, I do not see much point in pulling columns (like `c.c_id`, `c.desc`, `sm.user_id`) that are neither included in GROUP BY nor aggregated. (Yes, MySQL does allow you to do this, but those values don't seem to make much sense in your case.)

Answer (score 4):

Do this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4c84/21

using MySql's strengths:

```
set @userInquired := 1;

select s_id, t_id, c_id, dsc, 
    bit_or(user_id = @userInquired) as does_user_own_product
from tbl
group by s_id;

set @userInquired := 2;

select s_id, t_id, c_id, dsc, 
    bit_or(user_id = @userInquired) as does_user_own_product
from tbl
group by s_id;
```

common denominator SQL:

```
set @userInquired := 1;

select s_id, t_id, c_id, dsc, 

  case when sum(case when user_id = @userInquired then 1 end) > 0 then
     1
  else
     0
  end as does_user_own_product

from tbl
group by s_id;


set @userInquired := 2;

select s_id, t_id, c_id, dsc, 

  case when sum(case when user_id = @userInquired then 1 end) > 0 then
     1
  else
     0
  end as does_user_own_product

from tbl
group by s_id;
```

---

Common denominator SQL. Shortest technique if your database don't have proper boolean, use combo of `case when` and `max`:

```
set @userInquired := 1;

select s_id, t_id, c_id, dsc, 

  max(case when user_id = @userInquired then 1 else 0 end) 
       as does_user_own_product

from tbl
group by s_id;



set @userInquired := 2;

select s_id, t_id, c_id, dsc, 

  max(case when user_id = @userInquired then 1 else 0 end) 
       as does_user_own_product

from tbl
group by s_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, will test this out right now and get back to you in a few min

Comment: check it on SqlFiddle to quickly test it out http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4c84/3 ツ

Comment: It looks great and the fiddle works, I just need to change the variable names to make it work on my system

Comment: You can eliminate the "external" `case` by using `max` instead of `sum` and adding `else 0` to the "internal" `case`.

Comment: That's for other database :-) E.g. you cannot remove case when using Sql Server. If an inquired user appears twice or more on the group, the some would be two or more, hence still the need for external `case when > 0`

Comment: On second thought, regarding max technique, you are right :-) Will amend the query

Comment: I'm talking about `max(case when user_id = @userInquired then 1 else 0 end)`. This should work in any SQL flavour and doesn't require another `case` to check the result of `max`.

Comment: It's only two weeks ago I saw one of the wonders of [MAX technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254435/easiest-way-to-eliminate-nulls-in-select-distinct/10254603#10254603) on some problems and I quickly forget it today. Thanks for reminding :-)