# Select the non-null value if exists else null, but always select the row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope I can explain myself good, so I have 2 tables with one-to-many connection (TableA and TableB). Now, TableB has a column with a foreign key form TableA, and an ID (foreign key) to a third TableC. Now usually 2 to 3 rows share the same FK from TableA and this are my possible scenarios:

1. All rows with same FK_TableA have the same FK_TableC
2. All rows with same FK_TableA have NULL for FK_TableC
3. All rows with same FK_TableA have either NULL or same FK_TableC like so:

   ```
   TableB
   ----------------------------
   |ID| FK_TableA | FK_TableC |
   ----------------------------
   |1 |    123    |    321    |
   |2 |    123    |    321    |
   |3 |    123    |    NULL   |
   ----------------------------
   ```

So 2 rows can't have the same FK_TableA and different FK_TableC it's either the same or on has it an another is null or all null.

Now my question is how can I select the FK_TableC distinctively based on FK_TableA, in a way so  if any row with FK_TableA has a value (not null) select that value else null and join the results to TableA?

I have been trying with JOINS and FROM - WHERE but I always either lose or double rows. So from the table above I would need to select like so:

```
TmpTable
-------------------------
| FK_TableA | FK_TableC |
-------------------------
|    123    |    321    | => From Above
|    124    |    NULL   | => If all FK_TableC ware null
|    125    |    325    | => If at least one or all FK_TableC ware 325
-------------------------
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So wait, for table above you expect to get all this three rows? or just the first or?..

Comment: Just the non null value if exists, but I think I posted the question too fast this time, I think I found the answer using MAX and GROUP BY

Comment: Still didn't understand, but cheers. I think you can delete the question now.

Comment: I'm confused - aren't you just looking for a `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: @LesH if I use a `LEFT JOIN` I would get all rows, with `NULL` and `NON NULL` values, See what I did whit the TmpTable, if I were to use `LEFT JOIN` I would get all three rows (IDs: 1, 2 and 3) and my result would look : 
[| 123 | 321 |]
[| 123 | 321 |]
[| 123 | NULL |]
If I added DISTINCT it would only eliminate one of the 123 | 321 rows but I would sitll have the null, I want it without the NULL row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, thanks to the answer to this question [Easiest way to eliminate NULLs in SELECT DISTINCT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254435/easiest-way-to-eliminate-nulls-in-select-distinct), maybe I shouldn't have rushed with asking it. My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, C.ID_D FROM TABLE TableA A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT FK_TableA, MAX(FK_TableC) AS ID_C FROM TableB
GROUP BY (FK_TableA)) B ON B.FK_TableA = A.ID
LEFT JOIN TableC C ON C.ID = B.ID_C
```