# Remove Null if There are Other Non-Null Values

Tags: sql-server, null

How do I remove null value when there is other non-null value for a specific CaseNumber?

Below is the raw data (Table 1)

```
CaseNumber |  Date
-----------|-----------
A          | NULL
A          | 08/11/2017
B          | 07/11/2017
B          | 06/11/2017
C          | NULL
C          | NULL
D          | NULL
F          | 05/11/2017
F          | NULL
F          | 04/11/2017
G          | 03/11/2017
G          | NULL
```

Below is the result that I want.

```
CaseNumber |  Date
-----------|-----------
A          | 08/11/2017
B          | 07/11/2017
B          | 06/11/2017
C          | NULL
D          | NULL
F          | 05/11/2017
F          | 04/11/2017
G          | 03/11/2017
```

I'm using SQL server 2012.

Comment: Plz explain the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254435/easiest-way-to-eliminate-nulls-in-select-distinct#10254603).

[Easiest way to eliminate NULLs in SELECT DISTINCT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254435/easiest-way-to-eliminate-nulls-in-select-distinct#10254603)

In your case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1
WHERE Date IS NOT NULL OR CaseNumber IN (
  SELECT CaseNumber FROM Table1
  GROUP BY CaseNumber HAVING MAX(Date) IS NULL)
```

Comment: awesome thanks a lot for this. it also works like the answer above. really appreciate it !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might select distinct *CaseNumber* left join all records where Date is not null:

```
;with not_null as (
  select * from t
  where date is not null
), unique_case as (
  select distinct casenumber 
  from t
)
select unique_case.CaseNumber, not_null.Date from unique_case
left outer join not_null
on unique_case.CaseNumber=not_null.CaseNumber
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13a47/1) with fake data.