# Exclude rows distinct except for null values

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query that will return distinct rows while excluding rows that don't have maximum data.

table1

```
 col1     col2     col3     col4     col5
 one      a        b        c        d
 two      a        b                 d
 three    a        b        c        
 four     a                 c        d
 five     a        b        
 six      a        c        
 seven    a                          e
```

Basically, I want a query that will return the following from the table above

```
 col1     col2     col3     col4     col5
 one      a        b        c        d
 six      a        c        
 seven    a                          e
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly. What is the desired output? The one at the end? Why did you remove `tomcat/med.` but kept `tomcat/large`? If you want to skip certain rows, you certainly need to add such filter in the `WHERE` clause. For example, `WHERE color IS NULL OR disposition IS NULL OR...`.

Comment: Looks like the first half of my question was cut off. What I'm trying to do is write a query that will exclude rows with null columns only if there are existing rows that match on the remaining columns, and the same values are not null.

Comment: Oh, that's quite different. And are all columns nullable? How many nullable value columns are there?

Comment: Suppose only the first two columns are non-nullable

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Does each row have a PK?

Comment: Could col3 be `null` and col4 have a value?

Comment: Col1 is the only PK, and yes, Col3 could be null while Col4 has a value

Comment: Oh, previously col2 was non-nullable, LOL. And it's funny that you say col1 is PK but it's the same value for every row. :D

Comment: I only found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254435/easiest-way-to-eliminate-nulls-in-select-distinct) which is the same thing but just with one nullable field. With 3 nullable fields I'm afraid you need to work on a long query considering all possible combinations.

Comment: My mistake about col1 being PK. I'll update the example

Comment: Now you have two `col4`. :D I guess the last one should be `col5`. Anyway, what happens if col2-5 are repeated? Which `col1` do you expect to be displayed? This question started with a `distinct`, but now you don't even have repeated rows.

Comment: Maybe it helps to think about the problem this way. Rows 2-5 do not contain any data that is not already available in Row 1. I only want to return rows that have maximum data. Rows 6 and 7 also contain maximum data. So rows 1, 6, and 7 are all I want to show.

Comment: If you need the maximum value, then it seems the accepted answer if that question I linked should work for you. Of course, it needs to be adapted to several nullable columns.